# Export Images to Excel using ExcelJS

Tags: exceljs

```
addRowsToWorkbookVariant(worksheetObject, dataArray, SupplierId, wrkbook) {
        const excelObjectImgs = new ExcelManager();
        var data = null;
        //  var workbook =  excelObjectImgs.createWorkBook();
        if (dataArray != undefined && dataArray.length > 0) {
            var iLength = dataArray.length;
            var imagepath = "Website_URL/Images/Products/" + SupplierId + "/Thumbnail/";
            for (var p = 0; p < iLength; p++) {
                //var img1 = imagepath + dataArray[2].ImageName;
                var img1='Path of a image from Server';
                var ext = img1.slice((img1.lastIndexOf(".") - 1 >>> 0) + 2)
                if (ext == 'jpg') {
                    ext = 'jpeg';
                    console.log(ext);
                }
                console.log(img1);
                var ImageFile = wrkbook.addImage({
                   // filename: img1,
                   filename:'./Images/test/01_16102019_Demo.jpg',
                    extension: ext
                  });
                  console.log(ImageFile);
                worksheetObject.addImage(ImageFile, 'A2:A2');
                worksheetObject.addRow(dataArray[p]);
            }
            console.log(dataArray);
        }
    }
```

Currently using above approach to download images in excel using ExcelJS.

For that have to store each image in local Node repository but which will increase node repository size !
eg. filename:'./Images/test/01_16102019_Demo.jpg',

Is there any solution to convert image to base64 from (Server Path)URL and export it to Excel without saving it to local repository 
eg. var imagepath = "Website_URL/Images/Products/" + SupplierId + "/Thumbnail/";